# Can I make idli without rice?

Tags: rice, indian-cuisine

I want to avoid rice due to my diabetes. So can I make idli only with urad dal? Currently, I am using rice rava and urad dal in the same proportion and the idli comes out nice. Thank you

Comment: Welcome to the site. If you do a search for idli without rice there are many recipes to choose using all lentils or other pulses, why don't you look at those and if you have specific questions about the recipe? At this point your question looks like a recipe request, which is off topic on this site.

Answer (score 4):

You can also do it with Yellow/green Moong Dal or Millet. I used this recipe before - it's a mix pf Urad Dal and Millet https://masalachilli.com/proso-millet-idli-no-rice-idli-recipe/

Comment: I agree with this suggestion - plain yellow mung dal alone ferments nicely and makes pretty good idlis